# On returning to previous fragment inside onCreateView fires Button onClick()

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have two fragments, A and B.

From fragment A call fragment B:

```
B nextFrag = new B();
nextFrag.setArguments(bundleobj);
FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
transaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment, nextFrag); 
transaction.addToBackStack(null);  
transaction.commit();
```

Fragment B when user press back button:

```
FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
fm.popBackStackImmediate();
```

But then fragment A is loaded, onCreateView called and inside onCreateView I have a button:

```
doSomethingBtn..setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
}
});
```

The problem here is that onClick is triggered when returning back to fragment A.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of adding a nested `OnClickListener` to your button reference, implement it in your class and override the method to include a switch case based on the ID of the view that was clicked. Remember to change your button to `doSomethingBtn.setOnClickListener(this);` and see if that fixes the issue for you. If not, we will likely need more snippets from your actual code to find the cause.